# Add a subdomain to my Debian Server

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, domain, subdomain

I created a subdomain of a ndd i got with the A and i redirect it to my server with the IP

On my server i created an apache file to redirect that subdomain to the correct directory. Here is the config file - located in /etc/apache2/sites-avalaible/vietnam/

```
<VirtualHost*:80>                                                                                                                                                                                                      DocumentRoot /var/wwwvietnam.mysite.net                                                                                                                                          
  <Directory /var/www/vietnam.mysite.net/>                                                                                                                                          
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews 
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/vietnam_error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/vietnam_access.log combined
 </VirtualHost>
```

Then i added the config with

```
a2ensite vietnam
```

And i change the /etc/hosts with my subdomain name like this

```
11.22.33.44 vietnam.mysite.net
```

The thing is, when i open the `vietnam.mysite.net` in my browser it show the index.html located in the /var/www directory (ie the default file) it looks like apache don't understand the conf...

Any tips .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing some configuration in your virtual host settings.

As explained in Apache [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html#using) you need to specify following options for your named virtual host:

```
ServerName www.domain.tld
ServerAlias domain.tld *.domain.tld
DocumentRoot /www/domain
```

`ServerAlias` is optional, but usually you will want to use it.

In your case you need to specify:

```
ServerName vietnam.mysite.net
DocumentRoot /var/www/vietnam.mysite.net
```